# Getting data range from firebase with swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I would like to ask that question. The question is how to get specific data range from firebase ?

I have table on firebase like this:

```
  "users" : {
"Jz3IpatRWiWoDbiYM62q6qbHB503" : {
  "email" : "Kaanozdemir@gmail.com",
  "lastName" : "Ozdemir",
  "name" : "Kaan"
},
"PmeYYFiac0c55fU2sFpnTP308mC3" : {
  "email" : "kevinhart@gmail.com",
  "lastName" : "Hart",
  "name" : "Kevin"
},
"r0bMqSGCWihFi2EF4u6ckSzLP8v1" : {
  "email" : "Marcusalvarez@gmail.com",
  "lastName" : "Alvarez",
  "name" : "Marcus"
},
"A3tmSSGCWihFi2EF4u6ckSzLP8c1" : {
  "email" : "taylorswift@gmail.com",
  "lastName" : "Swift",
  "name" : "Taylor"
},
"3SUTsiGCWihFi2EF4u6ckSzLP8v2" : {
  "email" : "jimmyfellon@gmail.com",
  "lastName" : "Fellon",
  "name" : "Jimmy"
},
"lgSit3GCWihFi2EF4u6ckSzLP8u3" : {
  "email" : "jaxteller@gmail.com",
  "lastName" : "Teller",
  "name" : "Jax"
}
```

For example, I would like to get users values between 2 and 4 [2 - 4](Marcus Alvarez - Taylor Swift - Jimmy Fellon).

Is there any way to do that server side ? I don't wanna get all data and pick values that I want. Anyone knows?

Comment: Have you checked startAt() and endAt() methods?

Comment: Yes, I have checked but I couldn't find any way to solve my problem. These two methods take inside AnyObject. When I try to put in it Int, I'm getting error.

Comment: Please share the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also help if you share the relevant JSON (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Yeah excuse me, I'm new here. This is my first question. It might not be clear. I've edited question and added json. Can you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JSON DB structure to include an index in every node :

```
"users"  : {
     "autoID1" : {
         "email" :.....,
         "lastName" : ......,
         "name" :.......,
         "index" : //e.g.. 1,2,3,4......  
            }
      },
"noOfUsers" : 223,
```

If you are appending this users node via app, you have too keep track of the no of users in Database node `users` and keep updating the `noOfUsers` whenever a new user is added. And to set the next ones index number , just retrieve that node value i.e 223 and sees it and then increment the `noOfUsers`......

To retrieve between 2-4 .. Now you can use :

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "index").queryStarting(atValue: "2").queryEnding(atValue: "4").observe....
```

Comment: Thank you man. I really appreciate that. This is what I want !